# C++ Cannot convert from deferred::SafePtr<T> to T*

Tags: c++, casting

I have made a test case to show the problems I am running into. Please forgive me my ignorance on the issues of Deferred libraries and pointer casting. The only library included in the deferred.lib.

```
#include <deferred/deferred.h>

using namespace deferred;

SafePtr<Deferred> recordTime(int time)
{
    SafePtr<Deferred> d = createDeferred();
    SafePtr<CallbackData> p = new PointerCBD< char>( 0 );
    d->execute(p);
    return d;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while(1)
    {
        SafePtr<Deferred> d = recordTime(1000);
        d->waitHereForCompletion();
        char* c = dynamic_pointer_cast<char>(d->endResult());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try and compile in Windows XP with VS2008 I get:

> Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'deferred:SafePtr' to 'char *' with
>   [T=char]
>
> No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be called.

I have tried this command to return a pointer, rather than a SafePtr:

```
ManagerTimings* t = dynamic_pointer_cast<ManagerTimings>(d->endResult()).get();
```

Then I get this error:

> Error C2664: 'deferred::intrusive_ptr_release' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'char *' to
>   'deferred:ReferenceCountable *'

I have tried this command:

```
ManagerTimings* t = dynamic_pointer_cast<ManagerTimings>(d->endResult().get());
```

Then I get this error:

> Error C2784: 'deferred::SafePtr deferred::dynamic_pointer_cast(const deferred::SafePtr< U > &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const deferred::SafePtr< U > &' from 'deferred::CallbackData *'

Comment: Those `...` in your class definition are not valid C++.

Comment: We don't know what `SafePtr` or `dynamic_pointer_cast` do. Make a testcase.

Comment: Sorry, the ...'s are just where variables are defined that I didn't want to copy into the post. It is not in my actual code.

Comment: @Snowman0602: You have a mistake somewhere in your code, and you don't know where it is. So your deliberately mangling parts of it before showing it to us is probably not best wise! Instead of making your snippet uncompilable, invalid C++, **[make a testcase](http://sscce.org/)**.

Comment: I will make a testcase. Sorry I did not start with that.

Comment: What is the library you are using? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: I was under the impression that it was a standard library. I just found out that it was developed locally. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ManagerTimings* t = dynamic_pointer_cast<ManagerTimings>(d->endResult().get());
```

if you want to get an "unsafe" pointer, or probably this:

```
SafePtr<ManagerTimings> t= dynamic_pointer_cast<ManagerTimings>(d->endResult());
```

to get a safe `ManagerTimings` pointer. I don't know what library you are using, but I suspect that `dynamic_pointer_cast` can convert a `SafePtr` to another `SafePtr`. Or it just converts pointers.

Comment: I have updated my post to show a simple test case. I tried both of these suggestions with no success. I am using deferred.lib. The first suggestion for an "unsafe" point gave me this: Error C2784: 'deferred::SafePtr deferred::dynamic_pointer_cast(const deferred::SafePtr< U > &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const deferred::SafePtr< U > &' from 'deferred::CallbackData *'

Comment: The second gave me this: Error C2664: 'deferred::intrusive_ptr_release' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'deferred::ReferenceCountable *'

Answer (score -1):

```
&*d->endResult()
```

I think from this code endResult is the SafePtr you're having trouble with.